# PHP cannot get data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I`m using PDO to connect to the database.
My Connect class looks like this

```
class Connect {
private $error;
public static $dbh;
public $db;

public function __construct() {
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbName = "myproject";
    $dbUser = "root";
    $dbPass = "";

    try {
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbName}", $dbUser, $dbPass);
        $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SET NAMES UTF8");
        $query->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

}
}

$connect = new Connect();
```

sometimes when i try to get data from mysql using this class, it works but sometimes is doesn`t.

when I try to dump whole class, I`m getting this

object(Connect)#3 (2) { ["error":"Connect":private]=> NULL ["db"]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } }

I cannot understand what is the problem.

Comment: Why are you setting names?

Answer (score 0):

First remove your variables from the `__contsruct` function to avoid hard coding. When you create a new object from this class you can pass in your database information.

```
class Connect {
private $error;
public static $dbh;
public $db;

 public function __construct($host,$database,$user,$password) {


try {
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
    $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
     $query = $this->db->prepare("SET NAMES UTF8");
     $query->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
  }

  }
 }
```